# Resorting a TreeMap in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, treemap

I searched the web(and Stackoverflow) a lot but couldn't exactly found what I was looking for. Also couldn't really understand the concept.

As a Java assignment I have a treeMap storing some values in it.

```
static Map<String, Double> customers = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
```

Naturally it stores them ascending by it's String values. But I want it to store it's values  ascending by it's Double values. How can I achieve this by a comparator? Details would be much appreciated.

Also again in this assignment I've another, separate treeMap which stores different values. Again declared like below:

```
static Map<String, Double> customers = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
```

It's okay for it to store it's values ascending by String. I'm using it like this to print out it's values but I also need to print it's values in ascending order sorted by Double. So how can I re-sort a treeMap. Again, details would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are no built-in Map implementations that will let you sort by values.  None.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot re-sort a `TreeMap`. It has a fixed iteration order, determined at `TreeMap` construct-time. If you want a different sort order, use a different data structure.

> I'm using it like this to print out it's values but I also need to print it's values in ascending order sorted by Double.

So don't worry about sorting the `TreeMap`. Create a `List<Double>` of the values in the map, and sort those.

```
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(customers.values());
Collections.sort(values);
System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: An elegant solution but I have to use a TreeMap. Thanks anyway. :D

Comment: I didn't say you _can't_ use a `TreeMap`. You just can't print the sorted values without doing some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Make another map:

```
Map<Double, String> values = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
```

and always add to both maps (e.g. via a helper method). Unless there are memory constraints, you will get your `customers` maps sorted by customer and `values` sorted by whatever the `Double` value represents.

If you can have duplicate values, you can make a list (or a set, depending on the requirements) of customers instead:

```
Map<Double, List<String>> values = new TreeMap<Double, List<String>>();
```

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL I don't know - that's why I said "If you can". Set does help - this is duplicate values by (Double) value, (String) customers must be unique as the first map would otherwise be useless (i.e. some customers would be overwritten).

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realized you were using the `Map<Double, List<String>>` as an inverse of the OP's `customers` map. Sorry!

Comment: Genius. :) But sadly couldn't achieve what I wanted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What did you want? Maybe if you edit your question I can edit the answer to be more specific. It widely depends on the requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this was for an assignment I was previously working on and the deadline has been reached. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Ah, OK - well, hope you'll have better luck next time!